# How to change print orientation of a sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I implement code to change print orientation of a sheet depending on  selected case in my existing code?

E.g. Case 1 to Case 5 if selected then print on Portrait orientation and if Case 6 selected then print on landscape orientation.

I attached below my code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim IB As Variant
If Target.Address = "$F$2" Then
    IB = InputBox("Type Which Number Print Area To Use" & Chr(13) & _
      "Values Available are:" & Chr(13) & _
      "1 = Day 1" & Chr(13) & "2 = Day 2" & Chr(13) & "3 = Day 3" & Chr(13) & _
      "4 = Day 4" & Chr(13) & "5 = Day 5" & Chr(13) & "6 = Week/Signature", _
      "Print Area Selection")

    If IB = "1" Then
        Range("D4:G44").Select
        Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    ElseIf IB = "2" Then
        Range("H4:J44").Select
        Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    ElseIf IB = "3" Then
        Range("K4:M44").Select
        Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    ElseIf IB = "4" Then
        Range("N4:P44").Select
        Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    ElseIf IB = "5" Then
        Range("q4:S44").Select
        Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    ElseIf IB = "6" Then
        Range("D45:T76").Select
        Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    End If
End If

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

Application.EnableEvents = False

x = Range("F2").Value

Select Case x
Case 1
    Range("d4:g44").Select
Case 2
    Range("h4:j44").Select
Case 3
    Range("K4:M44").Select
Case 4
    Range("N4:P44").Select
Case 5
    Range("Q4:S44").Select
Case 6
    Range("D45:T76").Select
End Select

Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
Cancel = True

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the print orientation using `Worksheets("sheetname").PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape`

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.orientation) for more info.